# Hide the PIN entry on stock lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, privacy, 8.1-oreo

Is it possible to hide the visual feedback on the PIN entry on the Android stock lock screen?

The feedback makes it pretty easy for anybody standing near to watch the PIN:

[image]

I know that it is possible to disable the feedback when using a pattern, and I read tips that the pattern setting would also apply to the PIN entry, but I tried that and it didn't work.

I usually use the finger print sensor to unlock the phone, but on the rare occasions when it asks for the PIN ("for security") I always wonder why anyone would design a PIN entry screen like this.

I don't know if it matters, I'm using a bq Aquaris X. The Aquaris X5 I used before that had the same behavior (with Android 7), the HTC One before that did not (IIRC .. it's been a while).

Comment: I think it depends on the manufacturer of the phone. For instance, my Nexus 5 and 6 show the pin key press, but my samsung s9 does not. I have not found a way to enable/disable it. The closest I find is hiding password last character and keyboard popups.